# How to avoid edge effects in simulation models?

Tags: gis, simulation, agent-based-modeling

I am simulating individual movements in virtual landscapes using an agent-based model. I have different virtual landscapes varying in spatial aggregation of resources that have been built from Gaussian random field models (GRF). To avoid edge effects while simulating individual movements, I built a buffer around my virtual landscape (called A in the figures below). In particular, I performed a reverse clip from a large landscape with the same level of resource aggregation (called B in the figures below) and I merged it with my landscape A (see Figure 1). I also tested a landscape B with resources that are randomly distributed in the landscape (see Figure 2). Here are the results for 100-km buffers:

[image]

Which landscape would be best to use? Are there better methods to avoid edge effects? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One simple way is to make the world wrap around edges. I.e. make leftmost edge neighbor of rightmost, and topmost neighbor of bottom one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems ecologically unrealistic ?

Comment: It is a model anyway ;). As long as the size of the model is large enough, so that it is noticably larger than individual's range and characteristic size of features you are interested in, it might be ok.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I'm also working with real landscapes.